# Visual Studio publish AjaxControlToolkit error - The specified file could not be encrypted

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to publish a web project and in VStudio 2010 and I'm getting the following error:

```
Publishing directory /...
Publishing directory bin...
Publishing directory bin/ar...
Unable to add 'bin/ar/AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'bin\ar\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'.  The specified file could not be encrypted.
Error: The operation could not be completed 
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried deleting the the file in Solution explorer, but the file keeps re-appearing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The key was to disable the encryption on the folders where the development files to be publish are located.

If you encouter the problem you just need to open explorer, right click on the folder, select advanced, and you will find an option "Encrypt contents to secure data" --> make sure it is disabled.

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

PLease ansure that you have done the following things:

1)Included a reference to the dll in the references section in the solution explorer.
2)Made a reference at the top of the aspx page the ajax control is on, to the ajax toolkit.
3)Ensure that a reference to the ajax toolkit is in the webconfig.

If not then that will be your problem, if you need help doing this. Leave a comment on this answer

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with Ajax. I've unistalled ajax control kid and removed all references in the webforms. I've now have the encrypted error messages with picture files.Unable to add 'Images/CalculationsExamples.jpg' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Images\CalculationsExamples.jpg'.  The specified file could not be encrypted.
Unable to add 'Images/Calendar.jpg' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Images\Calendar.jpg'.  The specified file could not be encrypted.

.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem could be that the laptop I'm using is encrhypted. But I'm not sure if this is the problem and I don't know how to overcome this problem