# Ajax Toolkit controls not showing after Publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

```
<controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
</controls>
```

I have this in my web.config but it still won't import the controls on publish. It works with local debugger in visual studio.

Comment: may be you have different Debug and Release configuration (Web.Debug.Config and Web.Release.Config or how they usually called)?

Comment: Only difference in web.debug.config and release is: <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

Comment: There must be a problem with the ajax control toolkit, try removing it and re-adding or create a new project copy your files over and install it from nuget

Comment: May be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479772/visual-studio-publish-ajaxcontroltoolkit-error-the-specified-file-could-not-be

Comment: What is in output in VS when you make a publish in Relese mode?